# Using arara on bibtex in a subdirectory

Tags: bibtex, arara

I want to use arara to automatically create bibfiles. However, I'm having some trouble.

My folder sutrcture is as follows:

```
dissertation.tex
chapter1/chapter1.tex
chapter1/chapter1.bib
chapter2/chapter2.tex
chapter2/chapter2.bib
etc.
```

The file dissertation.tex imports all the chapters. When I run the following commands on the commandline:

```
xelatex dissertation.tex
bibtex chapter1/chapter1
bibtex chapter2/chapter2
xelatex dissertation.tex
xelatex dissertation.tex
```

I get the correct output. I thought I would automate the process with arara. In the header of dissertation.tex I've put:

```
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ chapter1/chapter1, chapter2/chapter2] }
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
```

But alas, when I run arara with verbose, I see that Bibtex reports:

`` I couldn't open file name `chapter1.aux' ``

Even though I see the file is there. Otherwise, arara works fine, but all the references are skipped. I double checked that if I do all commands by hand, I get the correct result.

So probably Bibtex is started in the wrong directory? Or am I using 'files' wrong? I cannot find this in the arara documentation how to use 'files'. Any help would be much appreciated.

The relevant arara log file lines are below:

```
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.287 INFO  - Welcome to arara 5.1.3!
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.295 INFO  - -----------------------------------------------------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.296 DEBUG - ::: arara @ C:\Users\Tommi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\arara
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.296 DEBUG - ::: Java 1.8.0_251, Oracle Corporation
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.296 DEBUG - ::: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.296 DEBUG - ::: Windows 10, amd64, 10.0
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.296 DEBUG - ::: user.home @ C:\Users\Tommi
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.297 DEBUG - ::: CF @ [none]
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.297 DEBUG - -----------------------------------------------------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.297 INFO  - Processing 'dissertation.tex' (size: 3.1 kB, last modified: 10/22/2020 20:55:54), please wait.
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.331 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 1: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.331 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 3: bibtex: { files: [ chapter-open-problem\paper, chapter-PNAS\PNAS2arXiv, chapter-NEURIPS\arXiv ] }
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.332 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 4: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.332 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 5: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.476 INFO  - I found a potential directive: Directive(identifier=xelatex, parameters={synctex=true}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[1])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.481 INFO  - I found a potential directive: Directive(identifier=bibtex, parameters={files=[chapter-open-problem\paper, chapter-PNAS\PNAS2arXiv, chapter-NEURIPS\arXiv]}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[3])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.483 INFO  - I found a potential directive: Directive(identifier=xelatex, parameters={synctex=true}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[4])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.484 INFO  - I found a potential directive: Directive(identifier=xelatex, parameters={synctex=true}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[5])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.489 INFO  - All directives were validated. We are good to go.
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.490 INFO  - -------------------------- DIRECTIVES ---------------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.490 INFO  - Directive(identifier=xelatex, parameters={synctex=true, reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\dissertation.tex}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[1])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.491 INFO  - Directive(identifier=bibtex, parameters={reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-open-problem\paper}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[3])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.491 INFO  - Directive(identifier=bibtex, parameters={reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-PNAS\PNAS2arXiv}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[3])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.491 INFO  - Directive(identifier=bibtex, parameters={reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-NEURIPS\arXiv}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[3])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.491 INFO  - Directive(identifier=xelatex, parameters={synctex=true, reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\dissertation.tex}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[4])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.491 INFO  - Directive(identifier=xelatex, parameters={synctex=true, reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\dissertation.tex}, conditional={ NONE }, lineNumbers=[5])
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.491 INFO  - -----------------------------------------------------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.494 INFO  - I am ready to interpret rule 'xelatex'.
23 okt 2020 10:17:34.497 INFO  - Rule location: 'C:\Users\Tommi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\arara\rules'
23 okt 2020 10:17:35.198 INFO  - I am ready to interpret task 'XeLaTeX engine' from rule 'XeLaTeX'.
23 okt 2020 10:17:35.199 INFO  - System command: [ xelatex, --synctex=1, dissertation.tex ] @ 
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.425 INFO  - ---------------------- BEGIN OUTPUT BUFFER ----------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.427 INFO  - This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
... some XeTEX output ...

23 okt 2020 10:17:51.428 INFO  - ----------------------- END OUTPUT BUFFER -----------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.432 INFO  - Task result: SUCCESS
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.435 INFO  - I am ready to interpret rule 'bibtex'.
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.437 INFO  - Rule location: 'C:\Users\Tommi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\arara\rules'
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.454 INFO  - I am ready to interpret task 'The BibTeX reference management software' from rule 'BibTeX'.
23 okt 2020 10:17:51.462 INFO  - System command: [ bibtex, paper ] @ 
23 okt 2020 10:17:52.276 INFO  - ---------------------- BEGIN OUTPUT BUFFER ----------------------
23 okt 2020 10:17:52.276 INFO  - I couldn't open file name `paper.aux'
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The files parameter is documented on page 21 (manual of version 5.1.3). Could you post arara's log file (the parts where the commands and their working directories are described)?

Comment: Hi TeXnician, I included the relevant parts of the log file. Note that in reality the chapter and tex names are not named chapter1\chapter1, but as you can see, for example,  chapter 1 is chapter-open-problem\paper. All bibtex outputs for the three chapters have the same pattern so I only included the first. Note that I'm on Windows 10, I'm not sure if that would make any difference. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom! We are investigating. Stay tuned! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `files` the correct way. We can check one of the `bibtex` directives from your `arara.log` file and confirm the absolute, canonical path (see the `reference` key, which is associated to the file being inspected):

```
Directive(
   identifier=bibtex,
   parameters={
       reference=C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-open-problem\paper
   },
   conditional={
       NONE
   },
   lineNumbers=[3]
)
```

The reason for `bibtex` failing is because, in that specific rule (as well as other TeX-related ones), the call to tho the `bibtex` binary on a file located other than the current directory is discouraged (in our case, we practically enforce this policy). We can see what happens:

```
return getCommand('bibtex', options, getBasename(reference.getName()))
```

`reference.getName()` means to only get the file name and ignore any path parts. Then `getBasename(…)` removes any associated extension. So, in our example:

```
reference  C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-open-problem\paper
reference.getName()  paper
getBasename(reference.getName())  paper
```

Then this rule will be evaluated to `bibtex paper`, as seen in the `arara.log` file:

```
System command: [ bibtex, paper ]
```

TeX tooling typically generates a lot of intermediate files and generating files outside the working directory is a can of worms. See, for example, [this discussion](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/46) in our project repository.

In version 5.1.0 of `arara`, released earlier this year (more precisely, on April 3th, 2020), we took a bold move and decided to use full, canonical paths everywhere to ensure proper coverage of the TeX tooling in virtually all possible scenarios (including relative paths and different working directories). Less than two weeks later (on April 14th, 2020), we had to revert this decision in version 5.1.1 (an emergency release) as the *vast majority* of TeX-related tools was failing because they were conceived to work with files in the current working directory and not any scenarios different than that (try, for instance, calling XeLaTeX on a file with an absolute path; the result is quite bonkers).

So, long history short: your directives are correct. The culprit here is, perhaps, the way the TeX tooling works. I can offer some alternatives to it, along the lines of a custom rule (however, I must say that this might open a can of worms, like fixing one thing and breaking another).

You can create a local configuration file in the root folder of your dissertation. I personally like `arararc.yaml`. Add the following content:

```
!config
paths:
- '.'
```

Explanation: we are adding the current directory (the root folder of your dissertation) as an additional rule path, taking precedence of the default set of rules shipped by `arara`. Now, let us create our own `bibtex.yaml` file:

```
!config
identifier: bibtex
name: BibTeX
authors:
- Paulo
- Tom
commands:
- name: The BibTeX reference management software
  command: >
    @{
        parent = reference.getParent();
        return getCommandWithWorkingDirectory(parent, 'bibtex',
               options, getBasename(reference.getName()))
    }
arguments:
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

What's new: I get the parent folder structure with `parent = reference.getParent();` so I end up with:

```
reference  C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-open-problem\paper
reference.getParent()  C:\Users\Tommi\Projects\dissertation\chapter-open-problem
```

Then I replace `getCommand(…)` by `getCommandWithWorkingDirectory(…)` which, as the name implies, runs the system command from the provided working directory. Then `arara` will display something like this (in `--dry-run` mode):

```
[DR] (BibTeX) The BibTeX reference management software
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Paulo, Tom
About to run: [ bibtex, mybib1 ] @
/home/paulo/SE/folder1

[DR] (BibTeX) The BibTeX reference management software
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: Paulo, Tom
About to run: [ bibtex, mybib2 ] @
/home/paulo/SE/folder2
```

The `@` symbol means `arara` will run the system command under that working directory. This will make your relative folders to be correctly identified.

Tree structure:

```
.
├── arararc.yaml
├── bibtex.yaml
├── dissertation.tex
└── ...
```

Sorry for `arara` not working as you expected. However, we had reasons to make the tool work that way, as the TeX tooling has some restrictions and interesting behaviours which sometimes go unnoticed to the end user.